# How to transit from one html page to another without a click

Tags: html, google-web-designer

I'm developing a web-based application in which I need to transit a from one HTML page to another after a specified time(say 2 seconds). I'm using Google web designer and pretty much new to this tool, as well as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Web Designer events and custom actions to achieve this.

In the Events panel, click the + button to add an event

Target: page1 or your page id

Event: Ready to present the page

Action: Custom > Add custom action

Configuration:

```
setTimeout(nextPage, 2000);

function nextPage() {
  document.getElementById('pagedeck').goToNextPage();
}
```

You can do this for every page and reuse this custom action.

Or you can also use goToPage method of pagedeck if you just want it to navigate to certain page using page id.

```
setTimeout(nextPage, 2000);

function nextPage() {
  document.getElementById('pagedeck').goToPage('page1_1');
}
```

where page1_1 is the page id of the page to go to.

You can see a list of APIs in our help documentation.
https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/6279926?hl=en&vid=1-635794172024313590-1514011264